# Double the result in count case when I join two table

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, case, distinct

I have two tables, and I want to join some column from 1 table to another

my table looks like this

School_tbl:

| School_ID | School_name | Division |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | School 1 | Division 1 |
| 2 | School 2 | Division 2 |
| 3 | School 3 | Division 3 |

Student_tbl:

| Student_id | Student_name | Gender | Grade | School_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | Manny | M | Grade 1 | 1 |
| S2 | Donaire | M | Grade 2 | 1 |
| S3 | Pandesal | F | Grade 1 | 1 |
| S4 | Donisya | M | Grade 1 | 2 |
| S5 | Jinki | F | Grade 2 | 2 |
| S6 | Apol | F | Grade 2 | 3 |
| S7 | Zuh | M | Grade 3 | 3 |

MY query is:

```
SELECT
  school_tbl.School_ID,
  School_tbl.school_name,
  School_tbl.Division,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Student_tbl.grade ORDER BY Student_tbl.grade) AS 'Grade',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN student_tbl.gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS 'Total Male',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN student_tbl.gender = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS 'Total Female',
  COUNT (DISTINCT (Student_id)) AS 'Total Student'
FROM
  Student_tbl
  LEFT JOIN School_tbl ON (school_tbl.school_id = student_tbl.School_id)
GROUP BY student_tbl.School_id
```

Expected output is:

| School_tbl.School_id | School_tbl.School_name | School_tbl.Division | Grade | Total Male | Total Female | Total Student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | School 1 | Division 1 | Grade 1, Grade 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | School 2 | Division 2 | Grade 1, Grade 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | School 3 | Division 3 | Grade 2, Grade 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

But what I get is:

| School_tbl.School_id | School_tbl.School_name | School_tbl.Division | Grade | Total Male | Total Female | Total Student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | School 1 | Division 1 | Grade 1, Grade 2 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | School 2 | Division 2 | Grade 1, Grade 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | School 3 | Division 3 | Grade 2, Grade 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

it doubles the result in total male and female,
I also tried putting distinct in count(case) like count(Distinct case gender = 'M' then 1 end) but then it returns 1 result in all rows in total male and female

Comment: I think you have to use `SUM(CASE when student_tbl.gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Total Male'` not COUNT.

Comment: @mjspier Not true, and the OP's current `COUNT` with `CASE` expressions are correct and should be working.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Your problem does not appear to be reproducible.  Can you add a fiddle/demo link to your question?

Comment: I don't think you've posted a complete data sample or your exact query to reproduce the _wrong_ results. Because, from your current data and query, it returns as expected. Furthermore, your query would be _incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by_.

Comment: @mjspier I already tried SUM(Case...

Answer (score 0):

I create the same tables that you mentioned and tested your query so the result:

change your query to:

SELECT

school_tbl.School_ID,

School_tbl.school_name,

School_tbl.Division,

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Student_tbl.grade ORDER BY Student_tbl.grade) AS 'Grade',

COUNT(CASE WHEN student_tbl.gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS 'Total Male',

COUNT(CASE WHEN student_tbl.gender = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS 'Total Female'

FROM

Student_tbl

LEFT JOIN School_tbl ON (school_tbl.school_id = student_tbl.School_id)

GROUP BY student_tbl.School_id